# Sum of absolute off-diagonal differences in numpy matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have a 2d numpy matrix and want to calculate the following test statistic.

[image]

I have brute-force code to do it, but it seems like there should be a more general numpy solution that works for any 2D matrix, using things like `np.diag()`. I can't figure it out though.

```
def bruteforce(m):
    s = 0.0
    for (i,j) in itertools.product(range(0,m.shape[0]),range(0,m.shape[0])):
        if i<j:
            n = (m[i,j]-m[j,i])**2
            d = m[i,j]+m[j,i]
            if float(d) != 0.:
                s = s+(float(n)/float(d)) 
            else:
                return('NA')
    return(s)
```

Where in this case `m` is an NxN matrix of integers. Is there a way to do it vectorised in numpy, avoiding brute force loops like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `m` is a square matrix, this will do the job:

```
import numpy as np
np.sum((m-m.T)**2/(m+m.T))/2
```

Here is a function that covers the case in which there is 0 in the denominator:

```
def find_s(m):
    d=(m+m.T)
    off_diag_indices=np.triu_indices(len(d),1)
    if 0 in d[off_diag_indices]:
        return 'NA'
    else:
        numerator=(m-m.T)**2
        denominator=m+m.T
        return np.sum(numerator[off_diag_indices]/denominator[off_diag_indices])
```

The reason that I used `off_diag_indices` is because we actually do allow to have 0 on the diagonal of `m+m.T`, because we never sum the elements on the diagonal.

Comment: Think you need `nansum` there to avoid `m` with `0` values.

Comment: Beat me by a minute. `np.nansum` to disregard entries where m is zero.  Also need to check for `inf` before summing (according to the calculation in `bruteforce`).

Comment: For performance though, I would suggest a mask rather than `nansum`.

Comment: @Divakar and Paul, thanks for the comments, I updated the answer.

Comment: I am not sure if the updated func `find_s` works. You need to use  a mask of `d!=0` before summing.

Comment: @Divakar, in the brute force algorithm of the OP, they return 'NA' if one of the elements in the denominator is 0. So if this happens I return 'NA', and otherwise I could just sum the whole thing right?

Comment: @MaxU The requirement of `nansum`/`masking` before summing makes it difficult for it.

Comment: @MiriamFarber Ah I see, that brute force is exiting out at the first instance of `0`. Thanks, should work now!

Comment: Why is returning `NA` here better than just dividing by zero and getting `np.inf`? Edit: Oh, because the OP does. Still think it's a bad idea